# How to copy file with ksh unix script to new directory after download?

Tags: bash, unix, copy, ksh

I have a ksh unix script which downloads a zip file to a tem directory. When download is finished, i want that the same script copy the zip file to other directory?

**How can i do it?**

```
#/bin/ksh
cd  /home/asha

FILENAAM=`/usr/sfw/bin/wget --execute=http_proxy=prox:8080 -q -O - -c    "http://www.dct.de/download/index.cfm?onderdeel=HTML_PC" | \
egrep -i "R.*Htm.zip" |  sed "s#.*\(\/download\/files/\R.*Htm.zip\).*#\1#"`

echo Current Name is $FILENAAM

/usr/sfw/bin/wget --execute=http_proxy=prox:8080 -q -O /tmp/htm.zip -c  "http://www.dct.de${FILENAAM}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about

```
/usr/sfw/bin/wget --execute=http_proxy=prox:8080 -q -O /tmp/$(basename ${FILENAAM}) -c  "http://www.dct.de${FILENAAM}" && cp /tmp/$(basename ${FILENAAM}) desired_directory
```

Comment: How can you be sure if download is finished?

Comment: @itro The wget is not run in the background so the second command does not execute until the first has completed. You can check the exit status with || to ensure wget gave a successful return status.

Comment: Just small correction: in `(basename ${FILENAAM}).zip` .zip doesn't needed. it create .zip.zip.

Comment: thanks a lot it works. the only concern is if download is succeeded the existing file zip will be overwrite and it is good but if in the middle of download something goes wrong and download is not succeeded, how can i recover old file?

Comment: if wget fails. file in tmp directory will not be copied